# Dividing an array in a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I have been given a task by my teacher and one of the questions wants me to divide everything in the array by `26.22`(A full marathon). I have been working on this all day and am totally stuck could someone please show me how to make this work?

this is what I have so far

```
import string

forename = []
surname = []
distance = []
farthest_walk = []
marathon = []
#Opening the text file and sorting variables
data = open("members.txt","r")
for line in data:
  value = line.split(',')
  forename.append(value[0])
  surname.append(value[1])
  distance.append(value[2])
#Closing the text file
data.close()

Results = open("Results.txt","w+")
Results.write("The number of whole marathons walked be each member is:\n")
for count in range(len(distance)):
  if float(distance[count])/ 26.22 = temp:
    marathon.append
    Results.write(forename[count]+":")
    Results.write(surname[count]+":")
    Results.write(marathon[count])
Results.close()
```

It is supposed to end up as `Forename`, `Surname`, `WholeMarathosRun` but I don't see how it could get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got there.
For each name, you need to compute how many marathons he ran, which can be achieved with the following operation:

```
 temp = float(distance[count])/ 26.22
```

This doesn't need to be in an `if` statement.

Then you need to write this value in the output file after the names:

```
Results.write(forename[count]+":")
Results.write(surname[count]+":")
Results.write(temp)
# line break such that each result stay in one line
Results.write("\n")
```

All those lines go inside the last `for` loop that you already have.

Comment: Thank you so much this helped me perfectly :)